# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar la función localStorage para almacenar y recuperar datos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web y necesito utilizar la función localStorage en JavaScript para almacenar algunos datos en el navegador del usuario y luego recuperarlos en futuras sesiones. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de cómo implementar correctamente localStorage y asegurarme de que funcione correctamente en diferentes navegadores y escenarios.

Mis principales dudas son:

¿Cómo puedo almacenar datos utilizando localStorage? ¿Hay alguna restricción en cuanto al tipo de datos que puedo guardar?
¿Cómo puedo recuperar esos datos almacenados en futuras visitas del usuario al sitio web?
¿Existe algún límite en cuanto a la cantidad de datos que puedo almacenar con localStorage?
¿Qué precauciones debo tomar para manejar posibles excepciones o errores al utilizar localStorage?

Comment: Bienvenido a stack overflow es. Recomiendo que investigues primero y después lo llevas a la práctica. Si hay algun error en la práctica que no puedas resolver regresas a este sitio y pregunta para ver como resolverlo.;). Te aseguro que hay muy buenas documentaciones en linea que explica esto con mucho detalle

Answer (score 4):

El [*localStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) es seguro para almacenar información no sensible, como el historial de navegación, las preferencias del usuario y los carritos de la compra. Sin embargo, no es apropiado para contraseñas, datos personales, números de credenciales o tokens de validación.
Todo depende del proyecto.

Para guardar información:

```
localStorage.setItem("nombre", "Luffy");
```

Para encontrar información:

```
localStorage.getItem("nombre");
```

Para quitar información:

```
localStorage.removeItem("nombre");
```

Para manejar posibles excepciones o errores al usar localStorage, use el método try...catch

```
try {
  localStorage.setItem("nombre", "Luffy");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Erro ao armazenar o item no localStorage: " + e.message);
}
```

No hay restricciones de tipo de datos, puede ser imágenes, texto, números, objetos o arrays.
El límite depende del navegador, pero en su mayoría es de megabytes.

un ejemplo completo:

```
function guardarEnLocalStorage(key, valor) {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valor));
      return "¡Item guardado correctamente!";
    } catch (e) {
      return "Error al guardar el item en el localStorage: " + e.message;
    }
  }
  
  
  
function buscar(key, personagem) {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  
    if (!storedData) {
      return "Ningún dato encontrado en el localStorage.";
    }
  
    const character = Object.values(storedData).find(
      (char) => char.nombre.toLowerCase() === personagem.toLowerCase()
    );
  
    return character ? character : "Personaje no encontrado.";
  }
  
  
function eliminar(key, personagem) {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  
    if (!storedData) {
      return "Ningún dato encontrado en el localStorage.";
    }
  
    const personagemLowerCase = personagem.toLowerCase();
    const updatedData = {};
  
    for (const key in storedData) {
      const char = storedData[key];
      if (char.nombre.toLowerCase() !== personagemLowerCase) {
        updatedData[key] = char;
      }
    }
  
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(updatedData));
    return "¡Personaje eliminado correctamente!";
  }
  
  
function todo(key) {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  
    if (!storedData) {
      return "Ningún dato encontrado en el localStorage.";
    }
  
    return Object.values(storedData);
  }
  
  
  
  

const value = {
    luffy: { nombre: "Monkey D. Luffy", posición: "Capitão" },
    zoro: { nombre: "Roronoa Zoro", posición: "Espadachim" },
    nami: { nombre: "Nami", posición: "Navegadora" },
    usopp: { nombre: "Usopp", posición: "Atirador" },
    sanji: { nombre: "Vinsmoke Sanji", posición: "Cozinheiro" },
    chopper: { nombre: "Tony Tony Chopper", posición: "Médico" },
    robin: { nombre: "Nico Robin", posición: "Arqueóloga" },
    franky: { nombre: "Franky", posición: "Carpinteiro" },
    brook: { nombre: "Brook", posición: "Músico" },
  };
  
const key = "value";
guardarEnLocalStorage(key, value);
console.log(buscar(key, "Usopp"));
console.log(eliminar(key, "Brook"));
console.log(todo(key));
```